# the sum of two numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of two numbers is $6$ times their geometric mean. Show that the numbers are in the ratio of $(3+2\sqrt {2}):(3-2\sqrt {2})$.

My Attempt:
Let the two numbers be $a$ and $b$.

By question

$a+b=6\sqrt {ab}$

Squaring on both sides

$a^2+2ab+b^2=36ab$

$a^2-34ab+b^2=0$

Comparing the above equation with $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$,

I could not move on from here. Please help me.

Comment: Easy way would be solving $a^2 - 34ab + b^2$ where $A$ = $1$, $B$ = $-34b$ and $C$ = $+b^2$

Comment: Divide the entire equation by $b^2$. Then, you get a quadratic in $\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the numbers be $a,ar,ar^2$

$$a+ar^2=6ar$$

As $a\ne0,$  $$r^2-6r+1=0$$

Comment: The question says two numbers. But why did you let 3 numbers.

Comment: @user335710, $$ar$$ is the GM

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
From $$a^2-34ab+b^2=0$$,

and assuming that $b\neq0$, divide through by $b^2$, giving:

$$(a/b)^2-34(a/b)+1=0$$

Then let $x = a/b$, so that

$$x^2-34x+1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a=0 \iff b=0$ then for other cases define $r=\frac ab$ which gives $r^2 -34r+1=0$